# How to create a auto increment variable in my sql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I want to create a auto increment variable in MySQL stored procedure whose value will be automatically incremented when ever executing a stored procedure.
Rather than retrieving the last entered value in MySQL table and manually increment it by 1

Comment: Please let me know that is it is possible in My SQL or not.

Comment: Both approaches -- looking at the last value in the table, and keeping a separate counter -- *are fundamentally wrong.*  What are you needing to actually accomplish?

Comment: I need a variable of int datatype to be declared in my procedure and  that automatically increment when ever i execute the stored procedure.

Comment: I understand that part.  The question is, what will you use this value for?

Comment: I will use this value at the last of my store code like                        'STIN(Pre defined value)' + 'Incremented value'

Comment: If you needed a monotonic `BIGINT UNSIGNED` then you could use the `UUID_SHORT()` function, but otherwise, the correct solution is an auto-increment primary key; insert into the table and the fetch the value using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until and unless you are not going to use a table, it is **not possible** to create an auto increment variable which you want. However if you are using the table then you can use the last insert value and then implement it.(*which you already stated and aware of.*)

Comment: Rahul Tripathi Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sequence (http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql/) and then use this every time you call your procedure. It basically is the same as the selecting from the table but still different.